# Empirical data on reuse of grounds, by flow and filter

Tags: brewing-process, filter, chemistry, ground-coffee

We wanted to know are there quality empirically generated chemical composition tables examining the relationship between filter porosity, flow by volume per time, and grounds of different varieties?

Comment: Hi and welcome to coffee! Solid puns, but I'm not sure they have a place here in Coffee.SE, much like they wouldn't belong in many other stack exchange sites, until puns.stackexchange.com becomes a thing. Perhaps they would be more appropriate in chat. As such I have edited your question to remove the background. I'm sorry if this has *bean* a negative first impression for you, I hope you will stay and continue to contribute.

Comment: Please see [this post](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/brewing-with-the-coffee-grounds-twice), as it may be related.

Comment: You mention "reuse of grounds" in your title but do not mention it in your text, can you elaborate?